# Factor space norm calculation when the subspace is finite-dimensional

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $(X,\|\;\|_X)$ be a normed vector space and let $M$ be a closed finite-dimensional subspace of $X$. I want to prove that:
$$
\forall x\in X\;\;\exists\;m\in M\text{  s.t.  } \|[x]_M\|_{X/M}=\|x+m\|_X
$$
I'm really lost with this one since I don't get at all what it says. The only thing I managed to do is that:

$\big($If any doubt, $X/M=\{[x]_M:x\in M\}$ and $[x]_M=\{y\in X:y\sim x\}$, where $y\sim x \Leftrightarrow\;y-x\in M$$\big)$
$$
\|[x]_M\|_{X/M}=\inf\{\|y\|_X:y\sim x\}=\inf\{\|y\|_X:y-x\in M\}=\inf\{\|y\|_X:y-x=m\;\text{  for  }m\in M\}=\inf\{\|y\|_X:y=x+m\;\text{  for  }m\in M\}=\inf\{\|x+m\|_X:\text{  for  }m\in M\}
$$
and got stucked here. Any ideas, comments and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show that the minimization problem $\inf\limits_{m\in M}{\|x-m\|_X}$ has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary. Then $\|x-m\|\ge 0,\,\forall m\in M\Rightarrow \inf\limits_{m\in M}{\|x-m\|_X}$ exists. Let $\{m_n\}$ be a minimizing sequence, i.e $\|x-m_n\|\to \inf\limits_{m\in M}{\|x-m\|_X}$. Because the functional $J(m)=\|x-m\|$ is coercive over $M$ it follows that $\{m_n\}$ is bounded in $M$ and therefore contains a convergent subsequence $\{m_{n_k}\}$ to some element $m_0\in M$ (because $M$ is finite dimensional and closed). For this subsequence you get
$$\|x-m_0\|=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}{\|x-m_{n_k}\|}=\inf\limits_{m\in M}{\|x-m\|_X}=\|[x]\|_{X/M}$$
In the above equality, we used the fact that the norm is continuous.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get two things: what does it mean that $\{m_n\}$ is a minimizing sequence and that $J$ is coercive over $M$?

Comment: A minimizing sequence is such sequence $\{m_k\}$ for which $J(m_k)\to \inf\limits_{m\in M}{J(m)}$. You can always take such sequence, because the set $\{J(m),\, m\in M\}$ is bounded from below and so the infimum exists.

Comment: $J$ -coercive means that $\lim\limits_{\|m\|\to\infty}{J(m)}=\infty$. It is easy to prove that the sublevel sets $S_\alpha=\{m\in M:\, J(m)\leq \alpha\} \subset M$ are bounded for each $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ if $J$ is coercive (by assuming the contrary and taking a sequence $\{m_k\}:\,\|m_k\|\to\infty$)

Comment: Then, from the coecivity it follows that the minimizing sequence $\{m_n\}$ is  bounded - it is contained in the sublevel set $S_{J(m_1)}$ (because you can take the sequence $\{m_n\}$ to be such that $J(m_k)$ to be decreasing.

Comment: Ok, thanks! And the fact that $M$ is finite-dimensional could not give that $\{m_k\}$ is bounded?

Comment: No, it can not give it. These things are standard tools in optimization. And your problem is exactly such. Also, if the answer helps, you may consider upvoting it, because I see you haven't upvoted many of the answers you got so far.

Comment: I'm trying to show that, since $J$ is coercive, $S_a\subset M$ are bounded $\forall a\in K$, but haven't got it:
Assuming the contrary, for some $a\in K$ we can get that $\forall k\in\Bbb N\;\;\exists m_k\in S_a$ s.t. $\|m_k\|>k$ which implies that $\|m_k\|\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}\infty$, but $J(m_k)=\|x+m_k\|\le a$ and I don't see how this makes a contradiction.

Comment: So you assume $\exists m_k\in S_\alpha$ s.t $\|m_k\|\ge k$ i.e $\|m_k\|\to\infty$.  But since $J$ is coercive, it follows that $J(m_k)\to \infty$ which is a contradiction with the fact that $J(m_k)\leq \alpha$ as $\{m_k\}\subset S_\alpha$. For the coercivity just use triangle inequality: $\alpha\ge J(m_k)=\|x+m_k\|\ge \|m_k\|-\|x\|\to\infty$ when $k\to\infty$

Comment: You may be also interested to see an application of this norm to something connected with the closed range theorem: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1691444/254733